# div.append not working for adding html

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to have a div element, that I can add ul element to it, my code looks like below:

```
$("#mydiv").append("<ul>");
$.each(data.d.results, function(index, value) {
    $("#mydiv").append("<li>");
    $("#mydiv").append(value["Title"]);
    $("#mydiv").append("</li>");
});
$("#mydiv").append("</ul>");
```

But what's happening, is once the line:  `$("#mydiv").append("<li>")` executes, it's closing it right away, so the `value["Title"]` is added after the closing tag for li.

Is this a normal case?

Comment: `append()` is not like `document.write()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using jQuery the wrong way, try something like this (untested):

```
var ul = $("<ul></ul>");

$.each(data.d.results, function (index, value) {
    ul.append($("<li></li>").text(value["Title"]));
});

$("#mydiv").append(ul);
```

Comment: cool this work. Note you can do it just by : `$("<ul>")` without the `</ul>`

Comment: Alright, feel free to accept my answer :-)